# Migration Struts 1.x to what?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jersey, struts

I have an application that was build with Struts 1.x and her front-end is JSP with FLEX (Action-Script), my idea is to change the front to Angular 6. And my back-end dosen't support REST.

What is the best option to Struts suport REST?
I should just add [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/), or upgrade the entire application to Struts 2.x or even more upgrade to SpringMVC?

Comment: It depends on how much time you want to spend. Converting a large, old S1 codebase to a REST-based app is certainly the easiest, but *how* easy depends on how well organized the existing codebase is.

Comment: Dave, you said this, but in your opinion what is the best solution not considering the time, just the best solution to keep the application with the standards of today?

Comment: *shrug* No clue. Depends on your actual requirements, whether or not you have to stay on the JVM, your existing ecosystem, the talent pool that will be working on it, what actual work needs to be handled on the back end, etc. You'll need to research on your own based on things only you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I have done Struts 2 work, but as I recall, I designed the system I worked on to have a business layer that would support Struts 2 and/or support a REST API.  The idea of having Struts in turn use REST, or in some way implement REST seems a bit convoluted to me.

I would suggest that you should take your Struts code and use the underpinnings as a basis to write a REST API.  Most of the underlying code should be reusable in that effort.  And then write your Angular code to use that new REST interface.

In fact, you may want to approach the problem the way I did: refactor your code to support a business logic layer that gives a solid definition of what you want to allow the upper UI layers to do.  Use that as a basis for your existing Struts code as a proof of concept that you can at least support the existing functionality.  Then you can use that layer as a basis for the REST API that would be used by an Angular UI.  You can then run both, if you want, as users are migrated from one to the other in small sets.  This will help with any scaling issues you might encounter in the new code base as well, as opposed to just "flipping a switch" and putting everyone on the new system, just hoping it supports the load.

Comment: Thanks JCampy! This really makes sense. I'll follow your advice and make this new interface just to communicate with the new front-end. And slowly moving the current UI to the new!

Answer (score 1):

[Here’s](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Running-Struts1-and-Struts2-together-td3487943.html) a discussion on whether it is good to have struts 1 and 2 co-exist in your server. I had a similar situation as you and I started developing all the new REST APIs using [struts 2 + REST plug-in](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/) and left the older APIs exist in struts 1. As I define newer REST APIs which are alternates to the older struts 1 based APIs, I deprecate the older APIs and remove the respective code.

Comment: Thank you Deva, for your answer, I'm considering making a REST APIs for the existing project in struts 1 and create a new application with SpringMVC with all the standards of today and migrating slowly the oldest  to the newest, and  my front-ends developers can switch the User Interface during the migration.